# Am I looking for help about i118 express node.js?

Tags: node.js, express

When i  choose some language, i get error message . that err msg is  .translation is not defined.
example :
http://localhost:5000/?clang=en

[image]

Can I achieve my goal with just these 23 files or do I have to use other methods as well?
my app.js code is

```
 // Imports
const express = require('express')
const expressLayouts = require('express-ejs-layouts')

const app = express()
const port = 5000

// import Router file

var session = require('express-session');
var path = require('path');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var i18n=require("i18n-express"); // <-- require the module
var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use(session({
  secret: 'secret',
  saveUninitialized: true,
  resave: true
}));
 
app.use(i18n({
  translationsPath: path.join(__dirname, 'i18n'), // <--- use here. Specify translations files path.
  siteLangs: ["es", "en", "de", "ru", "it"],
  textsVarName: 'translation'
}));

  
// Static Files
app.use(express.static('public'))
app.use('/css', express.static(__dirname + 'public/css'))
app.use('/images', express.static(__dirname + 'public/images'))

// Set Templating Engine
app.use(expressLayouts)
app.set('layout', './layouts/full-width')
app.set('view engine', 'ejs')

// Routes
app.get('', (req, res) => {
    res.render('index', { title: 'Home Page'})
})

app.get('/about', (req, res) => {
    res.render('about', { title: 'About Page', layout: './layouts/sidebar' })
})


// Listen on Port 5000
app.listen(port, () => console.info(`App listening on port ${port}`))
```

and my i have follow json file
[image]

Answer (score 0):

look at my codes

```
import i18nMiddleware from "i18next-express-middleware";
import { default as i18n } from "i18next";
import Backend from "i18next-node-fs-backend";

i18n
      .use(Backend)
      .use(LanguageDetector)
      .init({
        lng: "en",
        whitelist: ["en", "fa"],
        fallbackLng: "en",
        // have a common namespace used around the full app
        ns: ["translation"],
        debug: false,
        backend: {
          loadPath: path.join(__dirname + "/locales/{{lng}}/{{ns}}.json")
          // jsonIndent: 2
        },
        preload: ["en", "fa"]
      });
    this.app.use(i18nMiddleware.handle(i18n));
```

path locals/en/translate.js

```
{
  "api": {
    "events": {
      "email": "email",
      "fileMimiType": "File  mimi type is not allowed",
      "fileSize": "File size  Can not greater then "
    }
}

call it 

i18n.t('api.events.email')
```